# French translation of: "He who has a why to live can bear almost any how"

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire, citations

J'ai précédemment lu Man's Search for Meaning de Viktor E. Frankl et cette question m'est restée en tête assez longtemps avant que je la pose.

Comment traduiriez-vous en français : "He who has a why to live can bear almost any how"

Ma tentative est : « Celui qui a une raison de vivre peut presque tout endurer ». Qu'en pensez-vous ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

La traduction rend très bien le sens mais on perd l'effet de style mettant en parallèle *why* et *how*.

Voici ce que je peux proposer :

> **Qu'importe le comment à qui sait le pourquoi de sa vie.**

Comment: cool translation, it sounds better in french

Comment: I am citing your translation in my Operations Research thesis manuscript. :)

Comment: Glad to know, thanks! I took my inspiration from the beginning of *Qu'importe le flacon pourvu qu'on ait l'ivresse* :-)

Answer (score 6):

J'aime bien sous forme d'adage comme on a formulé dans une [autre réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/50810). En complément, ça semble provenir de Nietzsche dans le *Crépuscule des idoles*, 1888 ([texte](https://books.google.com/books?id=LhLlcQ-6dIEC&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&dq=%E2%80%9CGo%CC%88tzen-Da%CC%88mmerung%3B%20oder%2C%20Wie%20man%20mit%20dem%20Hammer%20philosophirt%E2%80%9D&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q=%22Hat%20man%20sein%20warum%22&f=false) ; [trad. anglaises](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2019/10/09/why-how/) ; « — Hat man sein warum? des Lebens, so verträgt man sich fast mit jedem wie? »). Dans une [traduction](https://books.google.com/books?id=9BX9DwAAQBAJ&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&lpg=PA8&dq=Cr%C3%A9puscule%20des%20idoles%2C%20%22son%20pourquoi%22&pg=PA8#v=onepage&q=Cr%C3%A9puscule%20des%20idoles,%20%22son%20pourquoi%22&f=false) en français on trouve :

> Si l'on possède son pourquoi ? de la vie, on s'accommode de presque
> tous les comment ?

Ça semble très littéral mais on le trouve ainsi dans plusieurs éditions...

Answer (score 3):

He who has a why to live can bear almost any how.

Avec un but, on vit, par tous les moyens.

Answer (score 1):

C'est une tentative qui serait selon mon point de vue presque le dernier mot sur la question de la traduction de cet adage ; je ne conteste qu'un terme, « endurer ». Il me semble que « how » ne soulève pas particulièrement la question de ce qui est douloureux ou pénible dans la vie, mais au lieu de cela ce qui représente un challenge ( \tʃa.lɛndʒ\ ou \ʃa.lɑ̃ʒ, [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/challenge)) ou un défi, pour employer le meilleur mot  français qui approche ce terme en tant qu'équivalent. C'est pour cette raison que je crois  le verbe « surmonter » plus exact que le verbe « endurer ».

- Celui qui a une raison de vivre peut presque tout surmonter.

Si on recherche plutôt une traduction près du langage d'origine la forme suivante me semble plus appropriée.

- Qui sait pour quoi il vit n'est pas arrêté par les comment.

Comment: No *comments*! ;-) « Comment » est invariable.

Answer (score 1):

Celui qui a un « pourquoi » dans la vie, trouve toujours un « comment ».