# Y a-t-il une nuance entre le substantif « pourquoi » et l'adverbe interrogatif employé en substantif ?

Tags: littérature, allemand, substantivation, adverbe-interrogatif

Y a-t-il une nuance (sémantique ou autre) entre le [substantif](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pourquoi#Nom_commun) *pourquoi* et l'[adverbe interrogatif](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pourquoi#Adverbe_interrogatif) employé en substantif ? Pourquoi dans une [traduction](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/50814) du texte de Nietzche on a conservé le point d'interrogation ; a-t-on déjà vu ça ailleurs ?

> — Hat man sein warum? des Lebens, so verträgt man sich fast mit jedem
> wie? / Si l'on possède son pourquoi ? de la vie, on s'accommode de
> presque tous les comment ?

Answer (score 1):

Pour une meilleure lisibilité, il aurait été plus judicieux de transcrire :

> Si l'on possède son « pourquoi ? » de la vie, on s'accommode de presque tous les « comment ? »